# Strange behavior while iterating over an array of numbers and parseInt

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, parseint

I'm there in JavaScript for a long time & it still gives me new things to learn.

According to me, the following line should print the same array back, perhaps it doesn't -

```js
console.log([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2].map(parseInt));
// output => [2, NaN, NaN, 2, 2, 2]

console.log([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2].map((num) => parseInt(num)));
// output => [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Could anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: Can you include the full script?  For instance, what is the code which generates that output?

Comment: done, added live snippet now

Answer (score 1):

yes so what are the arguments to callback of map

```
value,index,array
```

your code sample is executed like this:

```js
console.log(
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2].map((value, index) => {
    return parseInt(value, index);
  })
);
```

so you are passing second argument to parseInt , which is index

2nd argument to parseInt is `base` in which you want to parse the integer

for base 1 and 2 there is no digit `2` .. so it gives `NaN`

read more about 2nd parameter of [parseInt on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Fix is providing only one argument since your numbers are in base 10

```js
console.log(
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2].map(value => parseInt(value))
);
```

Comment: I have updated your answer with two code snippets

Comment: thanks @AmilaSenadheera for improving this.